# Modx Revo: getResources not displaying data

Tags: templates, content-management-system, modx, modx-revolution, getresource

I have a resource called 'My Projects' with the following getResources syntax:

```
[[!getResources? &parents=`5`  &tpl=`protmp` ]]
```

The chunk, 'protmp', I am using as a template is simple:

```
<div class="indivproj">
[[*pagetitle]]
</div>
```

Resource ID 5 has just two child resources under it. With the code above I would expect it to display their names.

Yet when I view the 'My Projects' resource I just get the title of the parent resources repeated 4 times, eg:

```
My Projects
My Projects
My Projects
My Projects
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

in your chunk the [[*pagetitle]]  should be [[+pagetitle]] also if you are still not getting results, omit the &tpl attribute from the getResources call and IF it is returning anything, it will dump the results directly to the page.

Comment: Thanks, adding the + did help, but oddly the parent isnt working. It displays all the titles of all published resources

Answer (score 0):

Got it: It seems to be a mixture of Seans answer and the fact the I wrote the line in with Text Editor on. I toggled it off and changed `[[*pagetitle]]` to `[[+pagetitle]]` and it works ok. Its odd because I thought this didnt matter....